# Can passengers on an airline use Travel John?

Tags: passenger-rights

For those scenarios, where plane is going through turbulence, or during take off or landing, or any other impractical scenario, can passengers carry and use [Travel Johns](http://www.traveljohn.com/) (albeit discreetly). Pilot's are allowed, so I'm thinking why not for passengers.

Edit: Link for Travel John

Comment: why would it not be allowed?

Comment: @Newton No liquids beyond 100 mL ;-)

Comment: Who is Travel John?

Comment: If child diapers are allowed, why wouldn't adult diapers be ? Many old people, who have deficiency in controlling their bodily functions use them and carry with them.

Comment: R*** Air actually makes it easier - they charge for drinks, so you don't drink much. I wonder how they actually serve disabled people, who simply can't walk to the toilet. Or they don't?

Comment: @pnuts When the query was posted, it had diapers in the heading so didn't click the link.

Comment: @DumbCoder Somebody had edited that to diapers, which I had to revert back to original, because diapers give a different meaning to it.

Answer (score 4):

I have flown with one myself once.

In the US (this also includes inbound/outbound international flights) the Americans with Disabilities Act requires the airlines to accommodate people with disabilities. Thus if you have a disability which requires you to keep a portable urinal handy, I don't see any legal way for the airline to restrict  it unless you create inconvenience to other passengers **and** the airline has no other way to accommodate you without creating this inconvenience. One might argue that using an adult diaper is better than Travel John, but if your flight is a 10hr flight, the diaper is not going to last that long, and changing it would be definitely more difficult than using a Travel John. For someone traveling on such flight with a broken leg - as it was my case - this really makes huge difference.

However outside the US (such as domestic flights in China) this might not be the case. Thus you better check with the airline, by calling their department related to people with disabilities.

You can do it even if it is just a matter of convenience for you - if it sounds way more convenient to you to carry, use and dispose the Travel John versus simply holding it up, this might indicate your special needs.